# load more functionality symfony 2.8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

So, I have entity, called Task.php, from which I get all chat messages from database and render on current page. Here how I get them in entity:

```
/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|static
 */
public function getDisplayedActivity()
{
    $limit = 15;
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->orderBy(['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
    $criteria->setMaxResults($limit);
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->isNull('parent'));
    return $this->activity->matching($criteria);
}
```

After I render them in twig file, like this:

```
{% for a in displayedActivity %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

There are now limit - only 15 messages shows on a page.
And I need button "Load More" that will load another 15 massages in the end of message block each time I will press it. But I have no idea how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine `setMaxResults` with `setFirstResult` for example:

```
$start = 0;
$limit = 15;
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->orderBy(['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
$criteria->setFirstResult($start);
$criteria->setMaxResults($limit);
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->isNull('parent'));
return $this->activity->matching($criteria);
```

In this way you can take from record 0 to 15

If you want to take record from 30 to 45 you need to change `start`  variable to 30.

So if you need to paginate you can pass the pageNumber for example page=1

```
$page = 1;
$limit = 15;
$start = ($page * limit) - $limit;
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->orderBy(['createdAt' => 'DESC']);
$criteria->setFirstResult($start);
$criteria->setMaxResults($limit);
return $this->activity->matching($criteria);
```

Comment: Well... and how can I call this method from my twig template by clicking on a button?

Comment: when I am doing like this -completely nothing happen.It seems setFirstResult() method ignored.